# Bind object to Select2 option?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, aurelia, jquery-select2-4

So I have a Select2 form:

```
<require from="./select2"></require>
<select select2="selected-values.two-way: selectedStuff" data-placeholder="Choose Stuff" multiple>
    <option repeat.for="thing of stuff">${thing.id}</option>
</select>
```

with which I can access `selectedStuff`, which is an array of the `id`s of the `thing`s that are selected. However, I would like instead to get an array of the `thing`s themselves rather than their `id`s. In my use case, it is not viable to look up a `thing` from an `id`. Is there any way to bind the `thing` object to the `<option>` element so that I can get the array of selected `thing`s rather than an array of selected `thing.id`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<option>` element's value attribute only accepts strings.  Use the model attribute to store non-string values:

```html
<select select2 multiple value.bind="selectedThing2">
  <option repeat.for="thing of things" model.bind="thing">${thing.name}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mEpr8E?p=preview

Here's the documentation on select binding with aurelia:  http://aurelia.io/docs.html#select-elements